# Is same Tag Names for Different Depths in XML valid?

Tags: xml, validation

I know this is a valid XML:

```
<ID>1</ID>
<NAME>ABC</NAME>
<Record>
    <PROFILEID>10</PROFILEID>
    <SIZE>100</SIZE>
</Record>
<Record>
    <PROFILEID>11</PROFILEID>
    <SIZE>120</SIZE>
</Record>
```

But I wonder is this valid?:

```
<PROFILEID>1</PROFILEID>
<NAME>ABC</NAME>
<Record>
    <PROFILEID>10</PROFILEID>
    <SIZE>100</SIZE>
</Record>
<Record>
    <PROFILEID>11</PROFILEID>
    <SIZE>120</SIZE>
</Record>
```

I mean can tags have same names for different depths? Or maybe can it have same name as its parent/child?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, its fine and normal, you'll just need to be careful with your XPath. You can use also namespaces to differentiate.

Comment: Technically, neither example is well-formed and therefore neither are valid because being well-formed is a prerequisite to being valid.   You can add a single root element to make both examples be well-formed, but you cannot assess validity without the specification of a schema.  Please see [Well-formed vs Valid XML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085)  and [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30461635/290085) for further details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, same-named XML elements can appear at "different depths" in a *well-formed* XML document.

[Validity is another matter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085) and depends on the schema technology being used.

In XSD, yes, same-named XML elements can appear at different depths and can have different types at those different depths if so defined locally.  **However, in XSD 1.0 same-named XML elements cannot have different types as siblings.**  In XSD 1.1, conditional type assignment can be used to allow same-named siblings to have different types.